# Does every point wise convergent $f_n$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence?

Tags: uniform-convergence

as the question above states - could you prove or provide a counter example to the statement that every pointwise convergent function has a UC subsequence?
 Also a bit unrelated but could you also recommend some explanatory videos on the subject similar to the ones prof Leonard has on YouTube? These subjects just don’t sit well with me.

Comment: $\chi_{(n,\infty)}$ is a counter-example. $\chi_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$ is another.

Comment: How so? I can you provide me some more details please

Comment: What is wrong with my question? I’m sorry it’s basic I’m just learning this stuff and couldn’t find or understand resources online

Comment: Perhaps the canonical example of a pointwise-not-uniformly convergent sequence of functions is $x^n$ on $[0,1]$, and this is a counterexample here as well.

Comment: After several simple counter-examples were provides in the comments you refused to work on them I think this question should have been closed before any answer was provided.

Comment: The thing is I really don’t understand how to approach this question, and a counterexample helps but it takes me a while to understand it. I don’t think it’s fair to say I’ve refused to think if I can’t formulate them into fully fledged solutions in a day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ is pointwise convergent to $f(x)$ over some domain $D$ if
$$
\forall \epsilon>0\ \ ,\ \ \forall x\in D\ \ ,\ \  \exists N(x,\epsilon)\ \ , \ \ n>N(x,\epsilon)\implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon
$$
and is uniformly convergent if
$$
\forall \epsilon>0\ \ ,\ \ \exists N(\epsilon)\ \ , \ \ \forall x\in D\ \ ,\ \ n>N(\epsilon)\implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon
$$
The sequence $f_n(x)=x^n$ over $D=(0,1)$ is pointwise convergent to $f(x)=0$ since
$$
\forall x\in (0,1)\ \ ,\  \ n>\log_x \epsilon \implies |x^n-0|<\epsilon
$$
but, there is no subsequence of $f_n(x)$ that is uniformly convergent.

Comment: Please do now answer questions when OP refuses to do any thinking. See the examples provided before you posted the answer.  You can also look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1